# Optimization: finding optimal inputs

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Posted a similar question earlier but was much too vague, hope this clears up my query:

I have a function `IVcal(rho,alpha,K)` and I want to find the optimal values of `rho` and `alpha` such that the data list `smiledata` (the output of the function for varying K) is the best fit possible to the data list `calibrate`:

```
xaxis = np.linspace(0.006,0.036,20)
calibrate = [calfun(K) for K in xaxis]
smiledata = [IVcal(rho,alpha,K) for K in xaxis]
```

The idea is that I want the graph `plt.plot(xaxis,smiledata, 'b--')` to be as close a fit to the graph `plt.plot(xaxis,calibrate, 'r--')` as possible by varying only `rho` and `alpha`.

I'm just not sure how to go about optimising to find these optimal values. I thought about taking the difference between `smiledata` and `calibrate` and minimising but again I haven't been able to find a good way to do so, particularly as I need the value of the input and not the output. I'd appreciate any advice and apologies for being vague before. Please let me know if anything else requires clarification.

Comment: What is the formula of IVcal (and calfun if you have it)?

Comment: [Hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) maybe?

Comment: They're both quite long formulae that refer to several previously-defined functions/expressions. I didn't think they would be relevant but if you need them I can try and condense them? Why do you want them if you don't mind me asking? I would ideally have a more general approach that would work for any data list of the same length as the smiledata one (calfun is just there to illustrate that I'm trying to approximate to find a 'best-fit' to another data set)

Comment: you can try gradient descent

Answer (score 1):

## Unconstrained

You could try using [scipy.optimize.leastsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html)

This is an optimisation method that aims to reduce the difference between a current set of values and a target set of values.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np


def calfun(k):
    """Example calibration function"""
    return k * 2 * 4

def IVcal(rho, alpha, k):
    """Example test function"""
    return rho * alpha * k

def error_function(x0, **args):
    """Calculates error between functions with current inputs"""
    xaxis = np.linspace(0.006, 0.036, 20)
    calibrate = np.array([calfun(K) for K in xaxis])
    smiledata = np.array([IVcal(x0[0], x0[1], K) for K in xaxis])

    # Get error between data
    error = smiledata - calibrate

    # Print square root of sum of errors
    print np.sqrt(np.sum(error**2.0))

    return error

# Initial guesses
rho = 1
alpha = 1
x0 = np.array([rho, alpha])

# Run optimisation
result = opt.leastsq(func=error_function, x0=x0)[0]
print 'opt rho: ', result[0]
print 'opt alpha: ', result[1]
```

Some notes:

- The quality of the optimisation is very dependent on your starting conditions!
- Converting the outputs of `calibrate` and `smiledata` from `list` to `np.array` allows you to compute the error between each value in both arrays without having to loop through lists
- Only the first entry in the output of the `opt.leastsq` is taken as this is an array of your optimised variables
- Printing the square root of sum of errors shows convergence of the optimiser

## Constrained

It looks like from `scipy` version 17 onwards there is a constrained version of least squared called [scipy.optimize.least_squares](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares)

From the link above:

> Lower and upper bounds on independent variables. Defaults to no bounds. Each array must match the size of x0 or be a scalar, in the latter case a bound will be the same for all variables. Use `np.inf` with an appropriate sign to disable bounds on all or some variables.

For your case I believe this would be

```
 bounds = ([rho_lower, rho_higher],[-np.inf, np.inf])
```

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to mention as well that rho is only meant to take values within a range - is it possible to restrict the domain of one of the inputs?

Comment: Added some info in the answer. Can't say i've tried it yet but i've used other optimize methods and bounding appears similar